# How to subselect values within a matrix but preserve their original dimension in R?

Tags: r, matrix

Quite a basic question with matrix in R: let's assume we have a matrix `m` and we want to select some of its element according to a boolean matrix (of same dim) `b` but keeping the original dimension e.g.

```
m <- matrix(1:9,3,3)
b <- m > 6 # just to have a boolean matrix
m[b]
# [1] 7 8 9

# Desired:
     [,1]    [,2]  [,3]
[1,]   FALSE FALSE 7
[2,]   FALSE FALSE 8
[3,]   FALSE FALSE 9
```

Is there an easy way to do that (like `drop=FALSE` when selecting a given column of the matrix to prevent its cast in numeric) or do I have to manually rebuild the original matrix?

---

#### Edit

Following @Darren Tsai comment `NA` instead of `FALSE` would be fine

Comment: A matrix can store elements with only one type. I think it's unlikely to put `boolean` and `numeric` into a matrix.

Comment: Yes good points, NA values instead would be OK, or a cast in data.frame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
m[m <= 6] <- NA
```

achieves your expected output, but its logic might be different from that of your question. The following solution is some complex but I think the concept meets `drop = FALSE`.

```
b <- m > 6

replace(array(dim = dim(m)), b, m[b])

# or

`[<-`(array(dim = dim(m)), b, m[b])

#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]   NA   NA    7
# [2,]   NA   NA    8
# [3,]   NA   NA    9
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confusing changing values in your matrix `m` with creating a new matrix.   Your `b` is just an indexer. Remember, in `R` , a matrix is just a vector with a class attribute that lets you display, and index, it with two dimensions.

If you want to know row and column, then

```
b <- which(m > 6, arr.ind =TRUE)
```

will give you the coordinate pairs, useful for subsetting the matrix later on.